# Как вывести общее количество тестов JUnit

Tags: java, maven, junit

Как вывести общее количество тестов `JUnit` в `maven`? Почему-то нигде нет информации об этом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартный плагин, который есть в parent Pom , должен показывать количество тестов. Может вы запускаете билд без тестов, посмотрите билд лог

Answer (score 1):

Используйте Cobertura, выведет общее кол-во тестов

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>
      <instrumentation>
        <ignores>
          <ignore>com.example.code.*</ignore>
        </ignores>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>com/example/mycode/**/*.class</exclude>
          <exclude>com/example/**/*Test.class</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </instrumentation>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>clean</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: капец, тривиальная операция и я должен для нее подключать джигура-плагин

Comment: @voipp можешь перевести проект на градл и написать собственный плагин)